# Spring Batch - execute a set of steps 'x' times based on a condition

Tags: spring-batch

I need to execute a sequence of steps a specific number of times.. any pointers on what is the best way to do this in Spring Batch. I am able to implement executing a single step 'x' times. but my requirement is to execute a set of steps - based on a condition 'x' times.Any pointers will help.

Thanks
Lakshmi

Answer (score 0):

You could put all steps in a job an start the whole job several times. There are different ways, how a job actually is launched in spring-batch. have a look at joboperator and launcher and then simply implement a loop around the launching of the job.

You can do this after the whole spring-context is initialized, so there will be no overhead concerning that. But you must by attention about the scope of your beans, especially the reader and writers.

Depending on your needs concerning failurehandling and restart, you also have pay attention how you manage the execution context of your job and steps.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will give it a try and update you with questions/issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a loop with SB using a `JobExecutionDecider`:

1. Put it in front of all steps.
2. Store `x` in job execution context and check for `x` value into
   decider: move to 'END' if `x` equals desidered value or increment it
   and move to first step of set.
3. After last step move back to start (the decider).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will give it a try and update you with questions/issues.

Comment: Using JobExecutionDecider I was able to execute same step x times.. but for multiple steps I am not sure how to use it. please can you tell me what this move to 'END' is? and how I can navigate between steps using this. Any links/ code will help thank u very much

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html (5.3.3 and 5.3.4)

Comment: Thank you Lucas, trying it out